# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie disappearing between request on a specific server

Tags: asp.net, iis, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have differing behavior between a test server and a dev server - on my dev server everything works fine but on the test server the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie disappears after a flow of events and hence so does the servers session. Testing was done in the same browser on the same machine & the code bases are virtually identical. The only significant difference is that the pages are being served from two different pcs.

The flow of pages (all https) that causes this is such:
Load page from domain A that contains an iframe (session cookie exists at this point).
Domain B is loaded into the iframe.
A second page from domain B is loaded into the iframe triggered from the first page.
The second page does a form post to back to domain A where the session cookie is now absent.

**EDIT**
Forgot to say - we're using SqlInMemoryProvider as our session state.

Answer (score 0):

You could share the session state between two servers using the below ways:

1)Using SQLServer Session:

In this mode of session state, the session objects are stored into SQL Server.

The benefit of using this technique is that all the data in the session will be stored together in a different location or you can say a centralized location in SQL Server, to get it working we just need to configure the SQLServer to store session data.

2)Using the StateServer Session:

In this mode of session state, the session objects are stored in a separate server handled by a Windows Service running on that server.

The benefit of using this technique is that all the data in the session will be stored together in a different location. In this case, the server to be handled by the Windows Service is named "aspnet_state"; this will become the centralized location for session data. To get it working we just need to configure the StateServer to store Session data.

when you share the session state between two servers make sure ASP.NET state service is installed on all the servers and the settings are as below:

[image]

Also, the service cannot be accessed remotely by default. To enable that option you need to set the value of the following registry key to 1: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection. Don’t forget to restart the asp.net state service after the registry key change.

You need to declare the session management options within the system.web node. Example:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=machinename:42424">
</sessionState>
```

If you want to use the SQL Server type then this section may look like the following:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"sqlConnectionString="the connection string name to the server">
</sessionState>
```

Where SQL connection string refers to the name of the connection string in the connectionStrings section of web.config which holds the details of the state table. The connection string itself may take up the following format:

```
<add name="ASPStateConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=[DB machine name where state DB is stored];Initial Catalog=ASPState;User ID=[db admin user name];Password=[db admin password]"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

we also need to add a machine and a validation key within the system.web node, that may look something like this:

```
<machineKey
validationKey="some long hashed value"
decryptionKey="another long hashed value"
validation="SHA1"/>
```

The default setting for the validation key is AutoGenerate which does exactly what the name applies: the key will be generated automatically by IIS. The default generation mode for the decryption key is IsolateApps. It generates a unique key for each application by using the application ID.

We need this common machine key as we want to run this on several machines so we don’t want the machine key to be automatically generated.

For more information you could refer this below links:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/07/01/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-5-session-state-management/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/load-balancing-session-state-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

It's because cookies are not stored if domains are different.
It's treated as 3rd party cookies.

You need to use same domain as parent site to iframe site.
Or else you need to use cookieless session.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently gone through this problem and come across the concept of cross-site cookies. If you want to share and use the cookie across the different domains then you have to set your cookie samesite attribute to None (SameSite=None). It must be secure otherwise it will be ignored and not send back to the server by browser (Chrome). To use a secure tag for your cookie you have to enable the HTTPS for your website.

For more detail you visit: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/